# dataframe with only one column , dropping nans does not work

Tags: pandas

I am trying to drop nans from one column in dataframe, but it does not work as expected.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({1:[np.nan,1,2]})
df[1] =df[1].dropna()
```

resulting dataframe still has nan. why?

Comment: IIUC, you are looking for `df=df.dropna(subset=[1]).copy()`

Comment: When you set `df =` pandas will align on index; it **cannot** change the length  of `df` on the left. In this case the RHS is a Series with index 1,2 so those rows get set. The missing indices, in this case just 0, are replaced with `NaN`. Since you started with `NaN` it seems as if nothing had been done, so a more illustrative example would be: `df=pd.DataFrame({1:[1,1,2]}); df[1] = df[df[1].eq(2)]`